# How to remove from string before __

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I got outputs from different suppliers (I am building a webshop).

The name of the shipping provider is in this format:

```
dhl_freight__233433
```

It could also be in this format:

```
postal__US-320202
```

How can I remove all that is before (and including) the __ so all that remains are the things after the ___ like for example 233433.

Perhaps some sort of RegEx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple approach would be to use [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-split) and then pick the second part that is the [`last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-last) part in this example:

```
"dhl_freight__233433".split('__').last
#=> "233433"

"postal__US-320202".split('__').last
#=> "US-320202"
```

Comment: [rpartition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition) is nice too.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /[^_]+\z/
```

```
"dhl_freight__233433"[r] #=> "233433"
"postal__US-320202"[r]   #=> "US-320202"
```

The regular expression matches one or more characters other than an underscore, followed by the end of the string (`\z`). The `^` at the beginning of the *character class* reads, "other than any of the characters that follow".

See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

This assumes that the last underscore is preceded by an underscore. If the last underscore is not preceded by an underscore, in which case there should be no match, add a *positive lookbehind*:

```
r = /(?<=__[^_]+\z/
```

This requires the match to be preceded by two underscores.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple Regexp and a ask the resulting [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/MatchData.html) for the post_match part:

```
p "dhl_freight__233433".match(/__/).post_match
# another (magic) way to acces the post_match part:
p $'
```

Postscript: Learnt something from this question myself: you don't even have to use a RegExp for this to work. Just `"asddfg__qwer".match("__").post_match` does the trick (it does the conversion to regexp for you)

Comment: Yes, it's often useful to review the docs for even familiar methods, here [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match). Nor was I aware that the argument ("patttern") could be a string (in which case it is converted to a regex), and I was reminded that `match` takes as an optional second argument the index at which the search is to begin, which one does not often see...

Comment: ...Moreover, I had forgotten about [MatchData#post_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-post_match) (and [MatchData#pre_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-pre_match)). (Note spelling of `post_match` in your last sentence.)

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, spelling improved

Answer (score 0):

There are many ruby ways to extract numbers from string. I hope you're trying to fetch numbers out of a string. Here are some of the ways to do so.

Ref- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125709

```
line.delete("^0-9")

line.scan(/\d/).join('')

line.tr("^0-9", '')
```

In the above `delete` is the fastest to trim numbers out of strings.

All of above extracts numbers from string and joins them. If a string is like this `"String-with-67829___numbers-09764"` outut would be like this `"6782909764"`

In case if you want the numbers split like this `["67829", "09764"]`

```
line.split(/[^\d]/).reject { |c| c.empty? }
```

Hope these answers help you! Happy coding :-)